# reason to change elliptic curves to normal form

Tags: algebraic-geometry, linear-transformations, elliptic-curves, rational-numbers

I would like to know about the concept of why we change the curve into Weierstrass normal form.
I mean for a specific example, if we have $x^3 +7y^3 + 64z^3=0$ and I went through all the steps and I changed it to $y^2= x^3 +ax^2 +bx + c$ .
I did this and I got very huge number like in trillions for $a, b, c$.
so we have $P$($2,2,-1$) belong to our first curve, what is this point considered w.r.t. the normal form?
I understood the process but I don't know why we do that and how can we find the rational points.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If the elliptic curve is in the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, then one can apply 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law to generate other rational point from existing one(s).

Comment: @Sahar Monlite - Another reason to use this construction is that when you describe your curve in terms of the "Weierstrass normal form" and the embedding into $\mathbb{P}^2$, a consequence is that you may parametrize "all elliptic curves".

Answer (score 4):

First of all, ultimately you need to deal with such curves without using explicit equations. The higher-dimensional analogues of elliptic curves (called abelian varieties) do not easily submit to equation-theoretic reasoning.

Even for elliptic curves, the group law is best thought of geometrically, not in terms of equations for the curve.

If we do use equations, a reason for working with Weierstrass equations is related to the definition of an elliptic curve over a field: it is not just given by a smooth cubic, but also must have a point defined over the field. A famous example of your type of cubic that has rational coefficients but *no* point with rational coordinates is $3x^3 + 4y^3 + 5z^3 = 0$ (viewed in $\mathbf P^2$, so $[0:0:0]$ does not count). The projective curve defined by this equation (in algebraic geometry) is smooth of genus 1 but it is not an elliptic curve over $\mathbf Q$.

Every curve over a field defined by a Weierstrass equation has a rational point over that field: $[0:1:0]$. This point is also rather special geometrically among all points on a curve defined by a Weierstrass equation: the tangent line to the curve at that point is the line at infinity $Z = 0$ and this tangent line meets the curve at $[0:1:0]$ with multiplicity 3 (it is called a flex point), not just multiplicity at least 2. This can help you figure out how to find the Weierstrass equation for an elliptic curve given by a different equation: make a change of coordinates to move the flex point to $[0:1:0]$ so that the tangent line to the curve at the flex point turns into $Z = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You asked about

> I would like to know about the concept of why we change the curve into Weierstrass normal form.

One reason might be that the curves entered into the
[LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/)
are given in terms of the Weierstrass normal form.
However, depending on context, you don't have to change to the
Weierstrass normal form. It is one of a few standard forms of
elliptic curve equations.

For example,
$\,y^2 + a_1 xy + a_3 y = x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_4 x + a_6,\,$
is a popular one for number theory. The original Weierstrass equation $\,y^2 = 4x^3 - g_2x - g_3\,$ has
[Weierstrass elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function) solutions. Some other forms include [Edwards curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve),
[Montgomery curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve), [Mordell curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve), and [Hessian curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_form_of_an_elliptic_curve).

Some integer points on your *homogeneous* curve
$\,C\!: 0 = x^3 +7y^3 + 64z^3\,$ are:
$$\,(2,2,-1),\,(4,0,-1),\,(5,-3,1),\,(8,-4,-1),\,(16,-12,5),\,(68,152,-73)$$
and infinitely many others. You can use a standard method to find
more points. For example, if $\,P\,$ and $\,Q\,$ are two
points on the curve $\,C$, then let $\,R := a P+b Q\,$
where $\,ab\ne 0\,$ and solve the equation
$\,0 = x^3 +7y^3 + 64z^3\,$ to find a new point.

For example, let $\,P := (2,2,-1),\,$ $Q := (4,0,-1).\,$
Then  $$R := a P+b Q = (2a+4b, 2a, -a-b).$$ The cubic equation
applied to $\,R\,$ becomes
$$0 = (2a+4b)^3 + 7(2a)^3 + 64(-a-b)^3 = -48ab(3a + 2b). $$
The nonzero solution is $\,a=-2,\, b=3,\, R=(8,-4,-1).\,$

The elliptic curve group law is given by any line
that intersects the curve at three points which are
now considered to have a group sum of zero.
The point $\,R_0 := (4,0,-1)\,$ is the group identity and
the point $\,R_1 := (2,2,-1)\,$ is a group generator. Now,
find that $\,R_{-1} := (8,-4,-1)\,$ is the additive inverse
of $\,R_1\,$ because $\,R_{-1} = 3 R_0 - 2 R_1\,$
is a solution of the cubic equation.
The line  $\,0 = x + 7y + 16z\,$ is tangent to $\,C\,$ at
$\,R_1\,$ and it intersects $\,C\,$ at $\,R_{-2} := (5,-3,1).\,$
Now $\,R_2 := (16,-12,5)\,$ is the additive inverse of
$\,R_{-2}\,$ because $\,R_2 = -R_0 + 4R_{-2}.\,$
Continue this [chord and tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law)
process to find any integer multiple $\,R_n\,$ of the point $\,R_1\,$ on the curve $\,C.$

---

However, it is possible to change your curve to Weierstrass
normal form with a few simple replacement steps.

The original curve is
$$ 0 = x^3 +7 y^3 +64 z^3. \tag1 $$
Scale the variables with the replacements
$(x\to x,\,y\to -z,\,z\to y/4)$ to get
$$ 0 = x^3 +y^3 -7 z^3. \tag2 $$
This curve appears in the solution to [MSE question 4298049](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4298049).
Apply the replacements $(x\to z-y,\,y\to z+y,\,z\to x)$ to get
$$ 0 = -6 y^2 z +7 x^3 - 2 z^3. \tag3 $$
This kind of step appears in the solution to [MO question 145877](https://mathoverflow.net/q/145877) by Noam Elkies.
Scale the variables again with the replacements
$(x\to 6x,\,y\to y,\,z\to 252z)$ and remove a common factor of
$1512$ to get
$$ 0 = -y^2 z +x^3 -21168 z^3. \tag4 $$
This is the homogeneous equation of a elliptic curve.
Dehomogenize by setting $z=1$ to get
$$ y^2 = x^3 -21168. \tag5 $$
which is in Weierstrass normal form, However, it is not listed
in the LMFDB in this form. Now use the replacements
$(x\to 4x,\,y\to 8y+4z,\,z\to z)$ and remove a common factor
of $64$ to get
$$ 0 = -y^2 z -y z^2 +x^3 -331 z^3. \tag6 $$
Dehomogenize by setting $z=1$ to get
$$ y^2 +y = x^3 -331. \tag7 $$
This is the curve
[LMFDB 441.d1](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/441/d/1).
The LMFDB gives the infinite order generator $P=(21,94).$

To conversion of points on this curve $(7)$ to the original curve
is given by the mapping
$$ (x,y)\mapsto(-8(y-31), -24 x, 2 (y+32)). \tag8 $$
For example, the generator $P$ is mapped to $(-504,-504,252)$
which is projectively equivalent to $(2,2,-1).$ Another example,
the double of the generator $2P=(7,3)$ is mapped to $(224,-168,70)$
which is projectively equivalent to $(16,-12,5).$

Comment: Thanks , but may I know how did you get these points?